# Angular-tree-component multiple times treeModel.update() on run time - makes the application slow

Tags: angular, treeview, angular-components

I am using [angular-tree-component](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/getting-started) in my application. In some cases, I need to add multiple nodes to my tree at run time. It may happen on every 1/2 second or even less than that. So when I am calling [tree.treeModel.update()](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/treemodel) for everytime, it makes the application slowness.

I know instead of calling update() function we can directly assign the value for tree nodes array. But the problem is, I need to add the new nodes at intermediate/any level of nodes. So iterating to the children of specific node is much difficult.

So kindly give me a solution for angular tree component multiple time update without any slowness.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview try this

Comment: Thank you. But in this project, suggested to use angular-tree-component. the solution in this tree type would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)